# How to use sync if I have such an array?

Tags: php, laravel

Good afternoon. I work with laravel and use sync. I get an array in this form:

```
[ 
0 => ['attribute' => '...', 'value' => '...']
1 => ['attribute' => '...', 'value' => '...']
...
]
```

Is it possible to stuff such an array into sync? If possible, can you tell me how to do it correctly?

Already used sync, but with an array of type:
`[0 => a, 1 => b, 2 => c, ...]`

Comment: I'm assuming the key is the relationship to sync, does the attribute value represent a pivot field in the relationship or?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `array_map` should be enough to make an array go from this

```php
[
    ['attribute' => 'name', 'value' => 'John'],
    ['attribute' => 'name', 'value' => 'Jane']
]
```

to

```php
[
    ['name' => 'John'],
    ['name' => 'Jane'],
]
```

```php
$mapped = array_map(fn($i) => [$i['attribute'] => $i['value']], $array);
```

Or, using collections

```php
$mapped = $collection->map(fn($i) => [$i['attribute'] => $i['value']])->all();
```